# Reading data from a PDF in an Android application

Tags: android, parsing, pdf

I need to read data from a pdf calendar like this:

http://www.consorziopriula.it/ecocalendario_schemi/Calendario%20Raccolte%202013%20TV2_definitivo%20NUOVO_Parte26.pdf

I've to do this in an Android application...is it possible?
If possible...which is the best method?

Comment: do you need to display pdf in android or extract only the contents and then display?. http://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/mobile/android_pdf_library.html

Comment: **Do you by *a pdf calendar like this* mean** PDF calendars identically built as your sample merely with different entries for the different days? In that case most parsing PDF libraries (e.g. iText, PDFBox, ...) should allow creating an application parsing these information. There are some quirks of that PDF to consider but nothing magical. **Or do you mean** PDF calendars with entries for individual days in general. That in my eyes might prove a Herculean task.

Comment: I need to extract data from this calendar (like events for each day) and then make an android calendar with those entries. The pdf calendar will be used to update events when needed.